# In the YAML format file as test.yaml, some MAC addresses will be judged as number

Tags: python, yaml

the MAC address of [80:41:26:53:24:11] has been judged as number 62745168251
 but [84:19:14:15:86:58] has been judged as string
[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. When posting questions like these, do not post images, copy and paste the actual code (much easier to try and reproduce your code and/or input that way).

Comment: You should also consdier taking the [tour], so you know what to do once you encounter an answer that solves your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't explicitly state it, but from the use of `yaml.load()` and
getting that result, my guess is that you are using PyYAML. **You
should not be using PyYAML `yaml.load()` as this is potentially unsafe
and completely unnecessary**. If you need to stick with PyYAML, use
`yaml.safe_load()` instead.

In the latest version of YAML]( (1.2 released in 2009) the [core
schema](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2805071) of what counts
as an int has [changed](http://yaml.org/type/int.html) from the
previous version (1.1 from 2005).  The most notable differences are
that `077` is no longer an octal in YAML 1.2 (use `0o77`) and that
[sexagesimals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagesimal), in the YAML
1.1 documentation indicated by this validation rule:

```
|[-+]?[1-9][0-9_]*(:[0-5]?[0-9])+ # (base 60)
```

are no longer supported in YAML 1.2 (not explicitly, and the YAML 1.2
specification points to the 1.1 language independent type, but the
example has been removed from the document).

In the YAML 1.1 documentation the explicit examples for sexagesimal
ints [are](http://yaml.org/type/int.html#id2439070) `190:20:30`,
[resp.](http://yaml.org/spec/1.1/#id858734) `3:25:45`.¹ This seems to
be an integer followed by **two** sets of (two digit) number and all
seperated by two colons (`:`), that can be used to indicate
e.g. hours, minutes and seconds. The rule (regex) however has no limit
on only two of these sets as the `+` at the end of `(:[0-5]?[0-9])+`
means at least one time and has no restriction. 
In a sexagesimal, between the colons, you can either have a one digit number from `0-9` or 
a two digit number where the first is restricted to `0-5`.

PyYAML is [documented](https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/) to feature a
YAML 1.1 parser (so it has not been updated although YAML 1.2 came out
in 2009). It will read your MAC addresses as sexagesimal, if they
match the rule, which roughly said happens when the **number between
the colons or after the last colon is less than 60**, as happens for both the values for key
`MAC1` and `MAC2` (the values are the same) in the value for
`NETWORK2`. The other MAC addresses have `:86:` in them and are not sexagesimals.

If you would dump these MAC addresses from a string using PyYAML, it will quote them for you when
necessary:

```
import sys
import yaml

d = dict(mac1='84:19:14:15:86:58', mac2='80:41:26:53:24:11')
yaml.safe_dump(d, sys.stdout)
```

which dumps:

```
{mac1: '84:19:14:15:86:58', mac2: '80:41:26:53:24:11'}
```

Please note that I did not do `print(safe_dump(d))` on purpose, it is
slower (as it has to first create and fill an internal buffer,
retrieve and stream out the contents). It also adds an extra empty
newline at the end of the output.

You can of course quote all (or all necessary) MAC addresses, but the
easier way is upgrade to a YAML 1.2 parser like the `ruamel.yaml`
package (disclaimer: I am the author of that package). Which, assuming
your input is in `network.yaml`, can be done using:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml as yaml

with open('network.yaml') as fp:
    data = yaml.safe_load(fp)
print(data)
```

which gives:

```
{'NETWORK1': {'BOND_MODE': 4, 'BOND_NAME': 'bond0', 'MAC1': '84:19:14:15:86:58', 'MAC2': '84:19:14:15:86:59'}, 'NETWORK2': {'BOND_MODE': 1, 'BOND_NAME': 'bond0', 'BLAN_ID': 820, 'MAC1': '80:41:26:53:24:11', 'MAC2': '80:41:26:53:24:11'}}
```

In round-trip mode, using the newer API, ruamel.yaml will not insert quotes when
dumping, as they are unnecessary for YAML 1.2:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from pathlib import Path

network_file = Path('network.yaml')

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
# yaml.indent(mapping=4, sequence=4, offset=2)
# yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(network_file)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

for result:

```
NETWORK1:
  BOND_MODE: 4
  BOND_NAME: bond0
  MAC1: 84:19:14:15:86:58
  MAC2: 84:19:14:15:86:59

NETWORK2:
  BOND_MODE: 1
  BOND_NAME: bond0
  BLAN_ID: 820
  MAC1: 80:41:26:53:24:11
  MAC2: 80:41:26:53:24:11
```

¹ <sub>You can also have a sexagesimal float: `20:30.15`</sub>

Answer (score 3):

You should always use quotes around string literals that start with a digit and consist of a mix of digits and non-digit characters to avoid confusion from the YAML parser:

```
MAC1: "80:41:26:53:24:11"
```

Otherwise, if your string literal consists of a series of one or two-digit numbers delimited by colons and all numbers but the first are between `0` and `59`, it would be interpreted as a [sexagesimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagesimal) number and would be converted to the equivalent number of seconds. For example, your MAC-address `80:41:26:53:24:11` would be treated as a sexagesimal number and converted to:

```
(((((80*60)+41)*60+26)*60+53)*60+24)*60+11
```

which is equal to `62745168251`.

Since your other MAC-address, `84:19:14:15:86:58`, has a number after the first number that is over `59` (`86` that is), it is not considered as a sexagesimal number and is therefore treated literally as a string.

Relevant source code can be found in the [`int` resolver](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/blob/master/lib/yaml/resolver.py#L192) and the [`int` constructor](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/blob/master/lib/yaml/constructor.py#L243).

Comment: I known this ,but I want the reason why some mac will be judged as number

Comment: A timestamp (not including date information) has a maximum of two colons indicating either HH:MM, MM:SS or HH:MM:SS. What YAML 1.1 parsers recognise are called sexagesimals and they don't have that restriction of two colons.

Comment: @Anthon Thanks for the correction. Edited accordingly then.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's going on with your syntax highlighting, but, maybe there's a clue there. Does removing some of the whitepaces *before* the MAC addresses make any difference?

If you want any of your values in yaml to be explicitly evaluated as strings, wrap the values in double or single quotes.

Comment: wraping  the values in double or single quotes will solve it, but I want know the difference between 80:41:26:53:24:11  and 84:19:14:15:86:58